# multiple temp variables at if/else scope

Tags: go

I've just noticed that we can declare a shadowing variable that scope to `if/else` statement as below

```
package main

import (
  "fmt"
)

func main() {
  num := 8


  if num := 9; num < 0 {
    fmt.Println(num, "is negative")
  } else if num < 10 {
    fmt.Println(num, "has 1 digit")
  } else {
    fmt.Println(num, "has multiple digits")
  }

  fmt.Println("num outside:",num)
}
```

Now my question is, is it true that I can only declare a single temp variable within a `if/else` statement?

I've tried both ways below but failed as hitting errors

```
//if num := 9; c := 10; num < 0 {..... //syntax error: c := 10 used as value

//if num := 9, c:= 10; num < 0 {..... //syntax error: unexpected :=, expecting semicolon or newline
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why, Go has tuple assignments. Try:

```
if num,c:=9,10; num<0 {
//whatever
}
```

Now that we are at it, you should note that the optimal statement (the one before `;`) can be more than assignments. It is legal to write:

```
if fmt.Println("something"); num<10 {
}
```

Comment: Edited in a new tip.